# How to register a .dll with electron-builder

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

In my project, there is an extra DLL file which is a direct show filter that needs to be registered to the system (windows).

I tried `child_process.execSync` but it requires admin privileges.

Is it possible to program electron-builder to register a .dll file after installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `electron-builder` You can use a custom NSIS script as shown [here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script).

You can use it to register your dll using the installer like this:

```
!macro customInstall

  ; Register your DLL
  Exec "regsvr32 /s $INSTDIR\path-to\your.dll"

!macroend

!macro customUnInit

 ; Unregister your DLL
  Exec "regsvr32 /s /u $INSTDIR\path-to\your.dll"

!macroend
```